# Php foreach in foreach loop not showing correct values

Tags: php

I am working on to save values in a csv file and this is structure of my array. All imformation is saving in right format. But when i am trying to save the value of "attribute field" which is array into array then it is showing same value for 2nd record even 2nd array don't have shipping attributes.If i will add foreach outside of main foreach then it is working but i need to run this into the same loop so that i can save all values in csv. This is my code.

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=searsparts.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
fputcsv($output, array('id','groupid','length','width','height','weight'));
foreach($partsDetail['item'] as $v=>$valPartsDetail)
{   
    $itemId = trim($valPartsDetail['Id']); 
    $productGrpName = trim($valPartsDetail['productGroupId']); 
    foreach ($valPartsDetail['attributes'] as $key => $attrVal) 
    {
        $explodeAttr = explode(' ', $attrVal['attributeValue']);
        if ($attrVal['attributeName'] == "ShippingLength") {
            $length = $explodeAttr[0];
        }
        if ($attrVal['attributeName'] == "ShippingWidth") {
            $width = $explodeAttr[0];
        }
        if ($attrVal['attributeName'] == "ShippingHeight") {
            $height = $explodeAttr[0];
        }
        if ($attrVal['attributeName'] == "ShippingWeight") {
            $weight = $explodeAttr[0];
        }

    }
    $partsData = array($id, $groupId, $length, $height, $width, $weight); 
    fputcsv($output, $partsData);  
    echo "length==".$length."==width==".$width."==height==".$height."==weight".$weight."<br/>"; 

}
exit;

Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [Id] = 0046795ADQ36006102
            [productGroupId] = 0046
            [attributes] =Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 116
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingLength
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 7 in
                        )

                    [1] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 117
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingWidth
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 1.75 in
                        )

                    [2] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 118
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingHeight
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 1.75 in
                        )

                    [3] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 119
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingWeight
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 1 lbs
                        )
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [itemId] =&gt; 00201589083
            [productGroupId] =&gt; 0020
            [attributes] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 152
                            [attributeName] =&gt; Part Type
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 121572
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [itemId] =&gt; 00460469083
            [productGroupId] =&gt; 0046
            [attributes] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 116
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingLength
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 13.9000 in
                        )

                    [1] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 117
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingWidth
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 2.5000 in
                        )

                    [2] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 118
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingHeight
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 2.5000 in
                        )

                    [3] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [attributeId] =&gt; 119
                            [attributeName] =&gt; ShippingWeight
                            [attributeValue] =&gt; 0.7400 lbs
                        )


                )
            [restrictions] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [restrictionId] =&gt; 7
                            [restrictionTypeCd] =&gt; SHP
                            [restrictionDescription] =&gt; Only Normal Shipping Allowed
                        )

                )

        )


)
```

Comment: how you are getting `$id, $groupId` inside  first `foreach()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start your inner loop, you need to clear out your variables.

The items that don't have these attributes are using the one from the previous iteration.

```
$itemId = trim($valPartsDetail['Id']); 
$productGrpName = trim($valPartsDetail['productGroupId']); 
$length = null;
$width = null;
$height = null;
$weight = null;
foreach ($valPartsDetail['attributes'] as $key => $attrVal) 
{
  ...
```

Comment: it will not work because all are itself vanished after each loop iteration itself.

Comment: No they don't, they are in the global scope of this example.